# Django Commenting framework and voting

Tags: django, digg, django-comments

I want to implement a commenting system for some pages by using the build-in commenting framework of Django.
The only addition to the default commenting framework is that other registered users can up/down vote comments (one time allowed indeed), just like Digg or Reddit style.

I have found [RedditStyleVoting](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/wiki/RedditStyleVoting) however it seems out of date and not really covering what I am looking for.

I will be grateful for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [django-voting](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/) application and allow vote for `Comment` objects.